# How to seek stream pointer of a memory mapped file(using boost)?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, boost, seek

I mapped my file to memory using `boost::iostreams::mapped_file_source` and declared a stream to read the file as `boost::iostreams::stream <boost::iostreams::mapped_file_source> streamReader`.

It worked fine and I was able to parse the memory mapped file. I used `getline` to read the entire file and  stored certain offsets from the file. While performing this operation I was able to use `seekg` to seek streamReader to desired position. But once the whole file is read, I cannot seek streamReader to anywhere.

`streamReader.fail()` returns true. Does streamReader clears the pointer once it reaches the end of file?

Is there some way so that I can go to the desired file offset after reading the entire file?

ThankYou

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you should call the `clear()` method of the stream to reset its state.

See http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/ios/ios/clear/

Comment: Yes... called clear() and now it works fine. So now I think it was because the failbit was set after reaching the end of file.. Thanks a lot John..